# How to get Browser to stop wrapping my entity data with <pre> tags?

Tags: java, google-chrome, safari, jax-rs, resteasy

I am trying to write a custom `ExceptionMapper` and I want to return `text/plain` but the `Response` that is returned or something in the chain insists on wrapping my contents with `<pre></pre>` tags.

Here is what I have tried, I tried without setting the `MediaType`:

```java
final Response.ResponseBuilder rb = Response.status(500);
rb.entity(e.getCause().getMessage());
return rb.build();
```

I also tried setting `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE` as well:

```java
final Response.ResponseBuilder rb = Response.status(500);
rb.type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
rb.entity(e.getCause().getMessage());
return rb.build();
```

In both cases I get my exception message wrapped in HTML:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
     <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
          com.google.appengine.api.oauth.InvalidOAuthParametersException:
     </pre>
   </body>
   <style type="text/css"></style>  
</html>
```

I think this might be the browser wrapping the contents, I get the same chunk of HTML wrapped around the plain text output exactly in Chrome and Safari, but I get the following when I use `curl`.

```bsh
[jhr@Blackintosh] [~]
curl http://funny-pages.appspot.com/image/all
com.google.appengine.api.oauth.InvalidOAuthParametersException:
```

**What do I have to do to get it to just display an undecorated contents back in a browser?**

Answer (score 0):

As long as `curl` gives you a plain text, it's a clear that the HTML wrapping comes from Google Chrome. This behavior can be (should be) configured on the client side. If you want to make sure that your clients always get a plain text file - send it as a [MIME attachment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME). In this case, Chrome will save a file and a user will have to open it using some plain-text viewer.